# AWS SES not sending emails to email addresses with same domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have setup three email addresses as identities. **All of them are verified identities in SES**.

1. address1@domain.com
2. address2@domain.com
3. **address3@domain2.com**

SES sends from address1 to address2, but i never receive the email in my inbox.

However, when i send email from **address1@domain.com** to **address3@domain2.com** or vice-versa i receive it in my inbox.

In short, AWS SES is only sending emails successfully outside of the domain(organization). I have checked the logs, the emails are being sent successfully. There are no bounces.

Any trick to this?

Comment: Are you sure that that email has not been send to the SPAM/etc?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the spam folders too

Comment: Are you sure that for this @domain.com there are no other MX records specified different mail servers?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, any update/solution?